# Pull Image from ECR to use in container for Jenkins running on Kubernetes k3s

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ecr

I have an image in ECR I want to use as a container in my jenkins pipeline.  My Kubernetes cluster is a k3s cluster running local.   I am unable to pull the image (I am guessing) because I am not properly passing my AWS creds (stored in a username with password secret homelab-k3s-ecr).  Through my searching I cannot find how to set the AWS creds when pulling from ECR.  Below is my Jenkinfile and the error.  Any guidance on how to pass the AWS creds to the kuberenetes agent config so that when I attempt to pull it can authenticate?

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: vapi
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  containers:
    - name: homelab
      image: <id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/homelab:1.0.0
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: homelab-k3s-ecr
"""
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                container('homelab') {
                    sh 'echo "Running build inside the ECR container"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
ERROR: Unable to pull Docker image "<id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/homelab:1.0.0". Check if image tag name is spelled correctly.
```

I have tried using the imagePullSecrets value as i found in the docs https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/ but i could not get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables

```
environment {
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('aws_access_key_id')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('aws_secret_access_key')
}
```

Read the offical docs
[using environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables)

Comment: could not get this to work since the env variables don't seem to be used by Jenkins to setup the pipeline, but instead in the pipeline.  I dont think the kubernetes plugin uses env variables.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is that you cannot use raw `AWS Access Key` and `Secret Access Key` to pull images from ECR. You need to execute login command `aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com` in 12h intervals since credentials are valid only for that time.

[Here](https://skryvets.com/blog/2021/03/15/kubernetes-pull-image-from-private-ecr-registry/) is some nice article describing how to create workaround for this and update `ECR` credentials automatically.